# How can I access to Google Drive from a Rails 3 app using omniauth + omniauth-google-apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth, google-drive-api

I'm trying to access to google drive using the [google-drive-ruby](https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby) gem but I haven't had success. That gem has an option to login with auth but I don't know how to get the access token from omniauth. The schema returned is [here](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Auth-Hash-Schema).

This is my code.

in models/user.rb

```
def self.create_with_omniauth(auth, role = 'user')
  create! do |user|
    user.email = auth['info']['email']
    user.first_name = auth['info']['first_name']
    user.last_name = auth['info']['last_name']
    user.google_token = auth['credential']['token']
    user.google_secret = auth['credential']['secret']
    user.role = Role.where(:account_type => role).first_or_create
  end
end
```

in controllers/sessions_coontroller.rb

```
auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
email = auth['info']['email']
user = User.find_by_email(email) || User.create_with_omniauth(auth)
```

and in controllers/documents_controller.rb

```
def index
  session = GoogleDrive.login_with_oauth(current_user.google_tocken)
  for file in session.files
    @docs << file
  end
end
```

I really hope someone can help me.
Thanks in advance